# Dump Go assembly for non-main package

Tags: go

I use the following command to dump Go's (pseudo) assembler:

```
env GOOs=js GOARCH=wasm go build -gcflags=-S -o main.wasm > asm.S 2>&1
```

This works well, but it only generates 1 assembly file that contains the contents of the "main" package.

I also want to dump the assembly for the "syscall/js" package. Specifically, I'm importing a function from the "syscall/js" package, and I want to dump the assembly for that function. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually build these packages:

```
go build ...flags... syscall/js
```